# How to stream my media via vlc using udp streaming method?

Tags: streaming, vlc-media-player, udp

I would like to know how to stream my media via vlc using udp streaming method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good guide of streaming with VLC is on the [VLC site](http://www.videolan.org/doc/streaming-howto/en/ch02.html)

I have copied it here for future reference but you really should check out the site first as specific instructions may change between versions.

> ### Chapter 2. Easy streaming
>
> **Table of Contents**
>
> [Intro](http://www.videolan.org/doc/streaming-howto/en/ch02.html#id343926)
>   [Streaming using the Wizard](http://www.videolan.org/doc/streaming-howto/en/ch02.html#id343937)
>   [Streaming using the GUI](http://www.videolan.org/doc/streaming-howto/en/ch02.html#id344652)
>
> ---
>
> ### **Intro**
>
> The easier way to start streaming with VLC is by using one of the
>   graphical user interfaces: wxwindows for Windows and GNU/Linux, the
>   skinnable Windows and GNU/Linux interface or the MacOS X native
>   interface.
>
> ---
>
> **Streaming using the Wizard**
>
> The Streaming/Transcoding Wizard leads you step by step through the
>   process of streaming your media on a network or saving it to your hard
>   drive. This Wizard offers easy to use menus but provides a restricted
>   set of options. Note
>
> The wizard is only available on the wxWindows interface.
>
> ---
>
> **Launching the
>   wizard**
>
> To launch the Streaming/Transcoding Wizard, open the "File" menu, and
>   select the Wizard menu item.
>
> [image: [D]]
>
> Launching the wizard
>
> ---
>
> **Wizard dialog**
>
> First select the type of task:
>
> - Stream to network: Choose this option if you want to stream media on network.
> - Transcode/Save to file: Choose this option if you want to change a file's audio codec and/or video codec, its bitrate, and/or
>     encapsulation method.
>
> [image: D]
>
> The Wizard Dialog
>
> ---
>
> **Input selection**
>
> Select a stream (such as a file, a network stream, a disk, a capture
>   device ...) by selecting the Choose... dialog or an existing item in
>   your playlist, using the Existing playlist item option.
>
> Partial Extract: To read only part of the stream, check the "Enable"
>   checkbox and choose a start and end date (in seconds). This option
>   should only be used with streams you can control such as files or
>   discs but not network streams or capture devices.
>
> [image: D]
>
> Wizard input selection
>
> [image: D]
>
> Wizard input selection from playlist
>
> ---
>
> **Streaming methods**
>
> If you chose Stream to network option, you can now specify the
>   streaming method. Available methods are:
>
> - UDP Unicast: Stream to a single computer. Enter the client's IP address (in the 0.0.0.0 - 223.255.255.255 range).
> - UDP Multicast: Stream to multiple computers using multicast. Enter the IP address of the multicast group (in the 224.0.0.0 to
>     239.255.255.255 range).
> - HTTP: Stream by using the HTTP protocol. If you leave the Destination text box empty, VLC will listen on all the network
>     interfaces of the server on port 8080. Specify an address, port and
>     path on which to listen using the following syntax [ip][:port][/path].
>
>   For instance, 192.168.0.1:80/stream will make VLC listen on the interface carrying the 192.168.0.1 IP address, on the 80 TCP port, in the /stream virtual file.
>
> [image: D]
>
> Wizard streaming method
>
> ---
>
> **Transcoding options**
>
> If you chose the Transcode/Save to file option, you can now specify
>   the new audio and video codecs and bitrates you want you input
>   converted to.
>
> (See Streaming, Muxers and Codecs)
>
> [image: D]
>
> Wizard transcode
>
> ---
>
> **Encapsulation method**
>
> Choose the method format. The UDP streaming methods require MPEG TS
>   encapsulation. The HTTP streaming method can be used with the MPEG PS,
>   MPEG TS, MPEG 1, OGG, RAW or ASF encapsulation. Saving to a file can
>   be done using any encapsulation format compatible with the chosen
>   codecs.
>
> (See Streaming, Muxers and Codecs)
>
> [image: D]
>
> Wizard encapsulation method
>
> ---
>
> **Streaming options**
>
> If you chose to Stream to network you can now specify several options.
>
> - Time To Live (TTL) This sets the numbers of routers your stream can go through, for UDP unicast and unicast access methods. If you do
>     not know what this means, you should leave the default value.
>
>   <kbd>Note: With UDP multicast, the default TTL is set to 1, meaning that your stream won't get accross any router. You may want to increase it
>     if you want to route your multicast stream.</kbd>
> - SAP Announce To advertise your stream over the network when using the UDP streaming method, using the SAP protocol, enter the name
>     of the stream in the text input and check the checkbox. This is NOT
>     available for the HTTP streaming method.
>
> [image: D]
>
> Wizard streaming options
>
> ---
>
> **Save to file destination**
>
> If you chose Transcode/Save to file you can now specify the file you
>   want to save the stream to.
>
> [image: D]
>
> Wizard save file - wxWindows interface
>
> You can now select the Finish button to start streaming/converting the
>   source.
>
> ---
>
> ### Streaming using the GUI
>
> **Introduction**
>
> A second way to set up a streaming instance using VLC is using Stream
>   Output panel in the Open... dialog of the wxWindows (Windows / GNU
>   Linux), skinnable (Windows / GNU Linux) and MacOS X interfaces.
>   Streaming methods and options used 99% of time should be available in
>   this panel.
>
> To stream the opened media, check the "Stream output" checkbox in the
>   "Open File/Disc/Network Stream/Capture Device" dialog and click on the
>   "Settings" button.
>
> [image: D]
>
> Open file dialog - wxWindows interface
>
> [image: D]
>
> Open file dialog - Mac OS X interface
>
> ---
>
> ### The Stream Output dialog
>
> [image: D]
>
> Stream output dialog - wxWindows interface
>
> [image: D]
>
> Stream output dialog - wxWindows interface
>
> **Stream Output MRL**
>
> On the wxWindows interface, a text box displays the Stream Output MRL
>   (Media Ressource Locator). This is updated as you change options in
>   the Stream output dialog. For more information on how to edit the
>   Stream Output MRL read Advanced streaming using the command line.
>
> **Output methods**
>
> - Play localy: display the stream on your screen. This allows to display the stream you are actually streaming. Effects of transcoding,
>     rescaling, etc... can be monitored locally using this function.
> - File: Save the stream to a file. The Dump raw input option allows to save the input stream as it read by VLC, without any
>     processing.
> - HTTP: Use the HTTP streaming method. Specify the IP address and TCP port number on which to listen.
> - MMSH: This access method allows to stream to Microsoft Windows Media Player. Specify the IP address and TCP port number on which to
>     listen.
>
>   <kbd>Note: This will only work with the ASF enacpsulation method.</kbd>
> - UDP: Stream in unicast by providing an address in the 0.0.0.0 - 223.255.255.255 range or in multicast by providing an address in the 224.0.0.0 - 239.255.255.255 range. It is also possible to stream to IPv6 addresses.
>     Note: This will only work with the TS encapsulation method.
> - RTP: Use the Real-Time Transfer Protocol. Like UDP, it can use both unicast and multicast addresses.
>
>   <kbd>Note:  UDP, HTTP, MMSH and RTP methods require to select the Stream option on
>     the MacOS X interface</kbd>
>
> (See Streaming, Muxers and Codecs) Encapsulation method
>
> Select an encapsulation method that fits the codecs and access method
>   of your stream, among MPEG TS, MPEG PS, MPEG 1, OGG, Raw, ASF, AVI,
>   MP4 and MOV. (See Streaming, Muxers and Codecs) Transcoding options
>
> Enable video transcoding by checking the "Video Codec" checkbox.
>   Choose a codec from the list. You can also specify an average bitrate
>   and scale the input. (See Streaming, Muxers and Codecs)
>
> Enable audio transcoding by checking the "Audio Codec" checkbox.
>   Choose a codec from the list. You can also specify an average bitrate
>   and the number of audio channels to encode. (See Streaming, Muxers and
>   Codecs) Miscellaneous options
>
> Select methods to announce your stream. You can use SAP (Service
>   Announce Protocol) or SLP (Service Location Protocol). You must also
>   specify a channel name. The Mac OS X interface also allows you to
>   export the description (SDP) file of a RTP session using the internal
>   HTTP or RTSP server of VLC, or as a file. This can be done using the
>   according checkboxes. The SDP URL text box allows to give the url or
>   destination where the SDP file will be available.

Comment: Don't you think you somewhat overdid the copy-paste thing?

Comment: yeah, i'll edit it out if you like...

Comment: it was mostly due to being told that it's difficult to determine if a link actually relates when browsing from arjan

Comment: it is like vlc 1.1.5 does not have these options...

Comment: it is possible....i would think the most recent version of vlc would have all pertinent options, although the switches may be different.

Comment: The VLC user interface has changed since about 1.0.1  All the options are there, they just look a little bit different.

Comment: I can successfully stream my playlist audio using above steps in LAN network. But playlist stops after 1 song or any other interrupt like track change. I am using this in mac os. I tried sout keep ,gather and sout all ,but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

this is videolan wiki about streaming: http://www.videolan.org/vlc/streaming.html
you can use it in command prompt or just by GUI as previous answer.